# How many JSON posts do I query for this web app?

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

I've been toying with the Wordpress JSON API today and I made a JQuery Mobile application that displays posts from my Wordpress blog. The query I do is this one `?json=1&callback=cb` and it gets me 10 posts. The only problem is: what if someone wants to see the 11th post? I haven't found any way to get it.

- I could set a count to `20` in my query but it'd only transfer the problem to the 21st post.
- Increasing the count every time the user reaches the limit would mean that all already seen posts (the 10 first) are downloaded again, for nothing.

I don't feel good about any of these solutions. I've seen you can search a post by:

- its slug: I don't know it.
- date: I know it is older than that of the post I am currently displaying, but the query needs the real date and I don't have it.
- category, author: doesn't help finding that 11th post.

Here's my code to give you an idea.

HTML:

```
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" onclick="loadPictureFromId(currentPictureId+1)">Previous</a>
        <h1 id="title"></h1>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" onclick="loadPictureFromId(currentPictureId-1)">Next</a>          
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    var currentPictureId;
    var myData;

    function cb(data) {
        myData = data;
        loadPicture(0);
    }

    function loadPictureFromId(id) {
        if (id<0) {
            alert("There are no more pictures!");
        }
        else
        {

            if (id>9) {
                alert("Feature not supported yet.");
            }

            else
            {
                currentPictureId = id;
                var temp = $("<div/>").html(myData['posts'][id].title).text(); // HTML entities
                $("#title").text(temp);
                document.title = temp;
                $("#img").attr({'src': myData['posts'][id].attachments[0].url, 'alt': temp, 'title': temp});    
                $("#facebook").attr({'data-href': myData['posts'][id].url});    

            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the plugin you are using:
 http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

Then the parameter you are looking for is `page` . If you set page to 2 in your request it will get posts 11 to 20. E.g. `?json=1&page=2&callback=cb`

The [README](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/json-api/trunk/readme.txt) details this.

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect! How did I not see this? It seems much easier to do than with a PHP query, which is what I was starting to think about.